# Sync Google Calendar in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

In my app I'm using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org). There are some events in a Calendar, using:

- [Angular-UI-Calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) `v.1.0.1`
- [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) `v.2.2.7`

The users of the application can: Create, Edit and Remove some event of this calendar.

How to put an option that the users can extract the calendar of my app to their personal Google Calendar? Is it possible? (Synchronize to Google Calendar).

Comment: You can integrate your Angular JS calendar to google calendar. For this , you should use Oauth authentication(https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). check the steps in the link. Enable calendar API in your console. check this link for how to integrate Angular js calendar to google calendar (http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Integrate-Angular-UI-Calendar-with-Google-Calendar)

Comment: Oh, but this is to display events from a public Google Calendar, isn't it? I want just the opposite. Display events from my BBDD, and if some user want, he can sync the events of my app in his personal Google Calendar.